# How can i set theme at run time?

Tags: android

Please Anyone know how to set theme using runtime?
getApplication().setTheme() not set theme?

How can i set theme when user select the button and it will set the theme in my application?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `setTheme(..)` before calling `setContentView(...)`and `super.oncreate()`  and it should work fine

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but here is the documentation for [ContextWrapper.setTheme(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#setTheme%28int%29):

> public void setTheme (int resid)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Set the base theme
>   for this context. Note that this
>   should be called before any views are
>   instantiated in the Context (for
>   example before calling
>   setContentView(View) or inflate(int,
>   ViewGroup)).

Based on this description, the activity needs to be destroyed and recreated (as it would normally on an orientation or other configuration change), then call setTheme() within onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

There is an open Google Android issue for this: it appears to be an open bug that you cannot programmatically change the theme with setTheme(). http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4394